# Angular2 router causes extra browser history entry

Tags: angular, router

In Angular2 I want to be able to navigate directly to a route and be able to hit back (in the browser) once to go to the last page that I was on.

If you first go to any website (I used google.com), then put this plnkr in your browser bar: http://run.plnkr.co/9D5IDnHv0UkUFM82/. If you hit the browser's back button, instead of taking you to the previous page, it keeps you on the plnkr until you hit back again.

I believe this is because although I navigated directly to the "home" route, when I hit http://run.plnkr.co/9D5IDnHv0UkUFM82/ (note that i set my base url to /9D5IDnHv0UkUFM82/) it routes me to the home url even though I am already there.

This problem also occurs in the Angular2 Tutorial app here: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html

Notice when the route loads, there is an extra entry in your browser's history. You can hit "back" on your browser and it will stay on the plnkr until you hit "back" again. This is not an artifact caused by plnkr. This occurs on my local angular2 setup as well.

Comment: Could you please give some more details.

Comment: What do you mean? The plnkr is a full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue

See also
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5025

There is already a pull request
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6069

Comment: Thanks! I thought I looked diligently through the github issues, but I guess I missed this one. Perhaps because it is so old.